# How to print the best parameters through GridSearchCV for k-fold cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I have used a GridSearch for parameter optimization when predicting values with 10-fold cross validation using sklearn, as shown below,

```
svr_params = {
   'C': [0.1, 1, 10],
   'epsilon': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1],
    }

svr = SVR(kernel='linear', coef0=0.1, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, cache_size=200, verbose=False, max_iter=-1)
best_svr = GridSearchCV(
    svr, param_grid=svr_params, cv=10, verbose=0, n_jobs=-1)

predicted = cross_val_predict(best_svr, X, y, cv=10)
```

I want to print out the best parameters selected by the GridSearch for `C` and `epsilon`. I would really appriate some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best parameters are available as [`best_params_`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) attribute of GridSearchCV.

```
best_svr = GridSearchCV(svr, param_grid=svr_params, cv=10, verbose=0, n_jobs=-1, refit=True)
best_svr.fit(X, y)
print(best_svr.best_params_)
```

Comment: It gives me this error `AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_params_'`

Comment: You need to use `fit`